# Multi-upload in PHP

Tags: php, forms, upload

I am trying to upload 2 files, the first one is a flash (.swf) file and the second a .png.

At the moment, I would have no problem making 2 different php upload file, with 2 different forms, but Im sure there can be a way to make that all together.

I am not really experimented with PHP, but Im trying to learn.

At the moment I have this:

```
<?php
      $allowed_filetypes = array('.swf','.png');
      $max_filesize = 10524288;
      $upload_path = 'swf/';

   $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
   $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

   if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
      die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

   if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
      die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['swf']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
         echo 'Your file upload was successful, view the file <a href="' . $upload_path . $filename . '" title="Your File">here</a>';
      else
         echo 'An unknown error occured, try again.';

?>
```

Ok so this is part of the code I found online, with that Im using a simple upload form.

How could I go and put 2 forms on the same page, and the 2 forms upload separately to 2 different folders, in example .png goes to icons/ folder and .swf goes to swf/ folder?

All that with only one button, that will also post other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

the `userfile` in `$_FILES['userfile']` is set by the value of the `name` attribute of the `<form>` in your html file.

so:

```
<form (.....)>
    <input type="file" name="userfile0"/>
    <input type="file" name="userfile1"/>
</form>
```

would result in

```
$_FILES['userfile0']
$_FILES['userfile1']
```

**Please note:**
Accepting files from the internet can be dangerous in many ways. make sure you do proper input sanitation and do not store the uploaded files in a web-accessible folder.

Comment: My html file is:

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p>
      <label for="file">Select a file:</label> <input type="file" name="swf" id="file"> <br />
      <label for="file">Select a file:</label> <input type="file" name="png" id="file"> <br />
      <button onclick="this.disabled=true">Upload File</button>
   <p>
</form>

So where would I add the $_FILES['swf'] and $_FILES['png']?

Here? if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['swf']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))

If yea, how can I do so?

Comment: You are on the right track. start experimenting and you will eventually get there. just take it one step at the time.